# jQuery UI - when should I use destroy method on the widgets

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-plugins

When I attach functionality to an element do I need to call **`.widgetName('destroy')`** before removing it from the DOM or does jQuery handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`remove`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/remove) .

I don't think this happens automatically, but then again, I don't think you need to call the `destroy` method as the `event handlers` are destroyed for you from the remove call.